# Where to still find a Debian 4.0 (etch) ISO?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-etch

I want to install debian 4 etch (due to compatibility reasons I can't use debian 5 lenny) but I can't find it.

I looked at the [debian archive](http://www.debian.org/distrib/archive), but it only lists 1.1 through 3.1, and the [getting debian](http://www.debian.org/distrib/) page only lists methods to install debian 5...

I'm sure I'm simply overlooking it but can someone point me to a place where I can find an ISO for debian 4? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the mirrors list for the latest release and found this mirror:

<del>http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/debian-cd/</del>
<del>http://ftp.riken.go.jp/Linux/debian/debian-cdimage/archive/</del>

They still have 4 available. This was the second mirror on the list so I imagine some of the other ones have it too.

Both of the mirrors are down as of today.

Comment: randomly clicked two and didn't see it, should have clicked some more I suppose :) thanks a lot

Comment: no problem, I probably would've done the same thing searching for myself.

Answer (score 7):

http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/

Comment: this is still working in case someone needs it.

Comment: It doesn't have all the ISOs. Most have the net installer, but it's missing the full offline ISOs. And due to the mirrors no longer exisiting the net ISOs most likely don't work for a full install.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, you are probably aware of this, but for anyone else stumbling upon this page, The Debian  Project has announced it's terminating security support for etch as of Feb 2010. (http://www.debian.org/News/2010/20100121)

Answer (score 2):

In http://snapshot.debian.net/ you can find debian packages from any version and any time

Comment: I did not know about snapshot.debian.org, this helped me get apache on a system I needed.

Comment: as of now snapshot seems empty.

Comment: Yep, snapshot is no more. It's just shows the default Apache2 page.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Either download an ISO from a still working mirror. (http://ftp.riken.go.jp/Linux/debian/debian-cdimage/archive/)
2. Download a „.jigdo” file for the image and compose the ISO yourself with the help of the `jigdo-lite` command.

Since the first option is quite straightforward, I'll give you an example for the latter. (Tested on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation.)

1. Install the [`jigdo-file` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/jigdo-file).
2. Create a directory for the downloaded ISO file.
3. Run the `jigdo-lite` command from inside this directory.

```
$ jigdo-lite

Jigsaw Download "lite"
Copyright (C) 2001-2005  |  jigdo@
Richard Atterer          |  atterer.net
Getting mirror information from /etc/apt/sources.list

-----------------------------------------------------------------
To resume a half-finished download, enter name of .jigdo file.
To start a new download, enter URL of .jigdo file.
You can also enter several URLs/filenames, separated with spaces,
or enumerate in {}, e.g. `http://server/cd-{1_NONUS,2,3}.jigdo'
jigdo:
```

4. Specify the „.jigdo” file (eg. http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/4.0_r9/i386/jigdo-cd/debian-40r9-i386-CD-1.jigdo) at the prompt.
5. Leave the prompt for the previously downloaded image file empty.
6. Specify your nearest mirror (usually the default is okay).
7. Wait for the download.

If everything worked out you should see the following message:

```
Finished!
The fact that you got this far is a strong indication that `debian-40r9-i386-CD-1.iso'
was generated correctly. I will perform an additional, final check,
which you can interrupt safely with Ctrl-C if you do not want to wait.

OK: Checksums match, image is good!
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, there are some full ISOs here: https://ftp.cae.tntech.edu/debian-cd/ Lowest version I see is `debian-31r5-i386-binary-1.iso`.